# How can I associate my Texture with my custom geometry

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

I'm a very green newb attempting to understand textures and geometries. I don't know what's wrong with my code, someone have one idea....

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load('../Programa/imagens/imagem.stl',function (geometry){
    var geometria = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry);
    geometria.computeBoundingBox();
    var max = geometria.boundingBox.max,
        min = geometria.boundingBox.min;
    var offset = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
    var range = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);
    var faces = geometria.faces;
    geometria.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++){
        var v1 = geometria.vertices[faces[i].a],
            ...``
        geometria.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
            new THREE.Vector2((v1.x + offset.x)/range.x, (v1.y + offset.y)/range.y),
            ...
            ]);
    }
    geometria.name = "Projeto 1";
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../Programa/imagens/uvmapping.jpg')
        }); 
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometria,  material);
    geometria.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometria.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.scale.set(0.029, 0.029, 0.029);
    scene.add(geometria);
    });
```

Comment: whats the problem?